# Lock symbol for uilabel

Tags: swift, xcode

A navigation bar button item has the option to set it to a "lock" symbol. this can be done in the options pane on the right hand side in Xcode. Is it possible to use this on a UILabel? maybe in code? because i can't find the lock item in the options pane for a uilabel.

Comment: I don't see the lock in `UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem`, but in SF Symbols, there is a lock. See https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any "lock" symbol for navigation bar button item. The closest I can think of is ".Stop". However, [SF Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/) can be used to represent both Lock or Stop. It'll be a good place to start